# Drag, Drop and Move Around Images

Tags: javafx, fxml, javafx-11

I'm creating an interface that allows users to drag an image from outside the program and drop it into an imageview within a gridpane.

Currently, the interface is able to handle drag and drop photos, but once its dropping and I cannot move it again.

```
@FXML
void imageViewDragDropped(DragEvent event) {
    Dragboard dragboard = event.getDragboard();
    if (dragboard.hasImage() || dragboard.hasFiles()) {
        try {
            photoImageView.setImage(new Image(new FileInputStream(dragboard.getFiles().get(0))));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    event.consume();
}

@FXML
void imageViewDragOver(DragEvent event) {
    Dragboard dragboard = event.getDragboard();
    if (dragboard.hasImage() || dragboard.hasFiles()) {
        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
    }

    event.consume();
}
```

How do edit the copied code to allow the photo that has been dragged and dropped to be move again?

Comment: *"to be move again"* -> moved to where?

Comment: JavaFX 11 is kind of old, I would recommend using a modern version (e.g. 21).

Comment: I don't see where you have `drag and drop` code on the nodes that you want to be able to `drag and drop`. `node.setOnDragDetected`, `node.setOnDragOver`, `node.setOnDragDropped`, etc.

Comment: Some [drag and drop resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71962336/1155209), in case that may help you.

Comment: There are three different dragging gestures. See [`MouseEvent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html). Which gesture are you having a problem with: simple _press-drag-release_, full _press-drag-release_, or _drag-and-drop_?